# AWS Quicksight import failed when I divide a calculated field

Tags: amazon-quicksight

When I add a calculated field to my AWS Quicksight dataset, the data import fails.
`datediff({birth_date}, now()) / 365.0`

**Import failed:
Too many rows were skipped while importing data into SPICE. Review your data and try again.**

But when I remove the division from my calculated field, the data is imported into Quicksight. What am I doing wrong?
`datediff({birth_date}, now())`

Thanks for your help
Ivan

Comment: Do you see any other error in the logs, explaining why the rows were skipped? If so could you share that? Also datediff returns an integer and you are dividing that with a float so that could be an issue.. try converting the output of datediff to a float before doing the division.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Converting to float was indeed the solution.

`intToDecimal(datediff({birth_date}, now(), 'MM')) / 12.0`